# 'ManyToManyDescriptor' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: python, django

I am making an application which obtains data and then displays it through graphics, the problem is that I am making a query to know when developers belong to a project, but it throws me an error I disagree that the ManyToManyDescriptor object does not have the filter attribute.

My view:

```
class ProjectTemplateView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

    def count_developer(self):
        projects = Project.objects.all()
        for project in projects:
            developers = Developer.project_set.filter(project=project).count()
            print(developers)


    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['projects'] = Project.objects.all()
        context['developers'] = self.count_developer()

        return context
```

This is my project model:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('approver', 'Aprovado'),
        ('process', 'En Proceso'),
        ('inactive', 'Inactivo'),
    )

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, verbose_name='Nombre')
    developer = models.ManyToManyField(Developer, verbose_name='Desarrollador')
    visibility = models.BooleanField(default=False, verbose_name='Visibilidad')
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, verbose_name='Estatus')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Fecha de Creacion')
    update_at = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now=True, verbose_name='Fecha de Actualizacion')
```

And this is my developer model:

```
class Developer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Fecha de Creacion')
```

Comment: Can you add complete error traceback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this maybe useful.

```
def count_developer(self):
    projects = Project.objects.all()
    for project in projects:
        developers = project.developer.all()
        # give you whole queryset
        print(developers)
        # will give you count
        print(developers.count())
```

another thing you should return developers from `count_developer` function so you can get developers count in template.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked for me, sorry, where can I find more information about project.developer.count ()?

Comment: @cosmosmulti if you follow updated answer then if you want count you can use `print(developers.count())` other wise if you want whole queryset then you can use `print(developers)`